# Configuring docker securly on a developer machine

Tags: ubuntu, docker

As a developer, I use docker and have a docker server running on my machine. I would expect that docker would not give my user permission to operate on files beyond my user's current set of permissions. The following example shows  that I misunderstand docker's security model or my system is misconfigured:

My user is unable to directly access the system's password file (`/etc/shadow`) without using sudo and providing a password:

```
% ls -l /etc/shadow
-rw-r----- 1 root shadow 1275 Dec 18  2016 /etc/shadow
% cat /etc/shadow
cat: /etc/shadow: Permission denied
% sudo cat /etc/shadow
[sudo] password for ryan:
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
```

However, my user is able to print the contents of `/etc/shadow` via the docker server **without the use of sudo or a password**:

```
% docker run -v "/etc:/share" alpine cat /share/shadow
... prints contents of the system's /etc/shadow
```

I assume this is possible because the docker server runs as the root user.

First, how much concern should this issue give me in terms of security? And if it is a concern, how may I correctly configure my development machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [Docker security | Docker Documentation - Docker daemon attack surface](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface) (emphasis is from source):

> "First of all, **only trusted users should be allowed to control your Docker daemon**".

**My take:**

Docker's primary goal is to provide isolation of programs / resources using the container concept - i.e., isolation of one container from another.

In order to do this, docker daemon needs superpowers (i.e., root privs). If you "own" docker daemon in some way (e.g., you are part of the docker group) and use that privilege, then you can use the daemon to exercise those superpowers.

From your example command line, it does seem that you are part of the docker group (otherwise you would have to use `sudo docker ...` ), so it is expected behavior for current versions of docker.

You might want to read that Docker security documentation a few more times to find out what you want to secure and how you can do it.

Comment: My take away from reading the security documentation is to remove my user from the docker group. That gives me the behaviour I want. Thank you!